# Curious Error when mounting M.2 nvme ssd ext4 partition on WSL 2. Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x80070032

Tags: wsl2

I am trying to mount ext4 partitions from M2 slot ssd on wsl 2. I am getting error  `Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x80070032`. The disk is listed below under model name CT500P2SSD8.  I am currently booted on on CT1000P3SSD8. Has anyone else faced this issue?

```
wmic diskdrive list brief
Caption                               DeviceID            Model                                 Partitions  Size

TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100V SCSI Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3  TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100V SCSI Disk Device  3           1000202273280
CT500P2SSD8                           \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  CT500P2SSD8                           6           500105249280

USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1 USB Device       \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1 USB Device       2           30762547200

CT1000P3SSD8                          \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  CT1000P3SSD8                          3           1000202273280


λ wsl --mount   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 --partition 3
The request is not supported.
Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x80070032
```

lsblk looks like so on drive CT500P2SSD8. It contains (in order) a Microsoft reserved partition, one windows ntfs drive, 4 ext4 linux drives, and 1 uefi fat 32 drive.

```
nvme1n1                    465.8G
├─nvme1n1p1                   16M
├─nvme1n1p2 ntfs            29.3G
├─nvme1n1p3 ext4     1.0   159.6G
├─nvme1n1p4 ext4     1.0    14.6G
├─nvme1n1p5 ext4     1.0    34.7G
├─nvme1n1p6 ext4     1.0   227.1G
└─nvme1n1p7 vfat     FAT32   199M

nvme1n1p1 is a Microsoft reserved Partition
```

I can mount ext4 partitions from  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3 (over sata 2.5" to usb 3) just fine.

I looked for error  Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x80070032 and I couldn't find anything specific. best I found was https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8280, which recommends enabling Hyper V feature. I have enabled Hyper V, VM and WSL. The issue still persists.

I suspected it was because of usbipd. I installed it from winget following [this connect usb tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb) in windows docs.

```
usbipd wsl list
```

But the output doesn't include the disk.

```
wsl --version
WSL version: 1.0.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.79.1
WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.2311
```

Microsoft Version: windows 10 Version 22H2 OS BUILD 19045.2311. (I have also verified on windows 11 version 22H2)

Background Information: I am trying to mount a ext4 partition for the following reason. I have been mainly using linux for the last 3 years in a dual boot arrangement. Recently I needed to use more windows only software. I decided to try out wsl2 and see if I can do better than dual boot. My goal is to keep a bootable linux drive that I also use for wsl2. I read it is challenging to near impossible to use a dual boot disk as wsl2 target([reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683650/run-existing-os-from-dualboot-as-wsl) and [reference2](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/qjva26/wsl_and_dual_boot_on_the_same_partition/)) . However mounting a partition as long as it is on a separate drive is possible.  If I can modify personal files I don't mind extra space replicating core apps I use within a lean wsl linux distro. I have a well ironed doom emacs installation plus org roam (emacs) directory where I keep my documents in my linux drive. My initial goal is to run emacs within wsl (wslg) on top of these documents, keeping only a single version across operating systems without syncing.

I have posted on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/zgap7r/curious_error_when_mounting_m2_ssd_ext4_partition) as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft article
[Mount a Linux disk in WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk),
you need to mount the disk and not the partition.

The first step should be:

```
wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 --bare
```

This will make the disk available in WSL 2.

Once the disk is mounted, its partitions can be listed by
running the following command inside WSL 2:

```
lsblk
```

This will display the available block devices and their partitions.
You may then access the mounted partitions using the Linux syntax of
`/dev/<Device><Partition>`.

Comment: wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 --bare
also returns the same error.
The request is not supported.
Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x80070032

Comment: (1) Is this a USB disk, or anything else than a normal internal disk? (2) Is the Hyper-V service enabled? (3) Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: 1) the ssd is connected to the m.2 nvme slot of my computer. 2) I have enabled hyper-v.  3) I haven't tried. I will get back to you one this shortly.